# How do I track incoming IP addresses on Windows 2003 web server?

Tags: website, windows-server-2003, web-server, ip, traffic

How do I track incoming IP addresses that visit a website hosted on a Windows 2003 web server? I know we can use Google Analytics to do the job,is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All webservers have logs, where they can be found depends on what webserver you have.

Comment: @ Nifle I have got a IIS server on a windows 2003 machine,any idea where i could find that log file?thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend, (search: 2003 IIS access log): **[How to configure Web site logging in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324279)**